# Linq to SQL Bombing Out on DataContext

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datacontext

For some reason my code just decided to stop working after doing a build and not sure what the issue is.

public class clsSaveError
  {

```
  public clsSendEmail.clsSendEmail SendEmail = new clsSendEmail.clsSendEmail();
  public clsSettings.clsSEttings Settings = new clsSettings.clsSEttings();
  public clsLinqToSQL.K12DataClassesDataContext dbContext = new clsLinqToSQL.K12DataClassesDataContext();


    public void InsertErrorIntoDatabase(string monsterID, string dbtable, string errormessage, string stacktrace, EventLog log)
    {
        clsLinqToSQL.K12DataClassesDataContext dbContext = new clsLinqToSQL.K12DataClassesDataContext();


          try
          {
              dbContext.tblErrors err = new dbContext.tblErrors();
              err.monsterid = monsterID;
              err.dbtable = dbtable;
              err.errormessage = errormessage;
              err.stacktrace = stacktrace;
              dbContext.tblErrors.Insertonsubmit(err);
              dbContext.SubmitChanges();
          }
          catch (Exception except)
          {
              //write the error to the event log
              log.WriteEntry("ERROR! Unable to write error to database. Here are the details:" + "\n" +
                  "Exception Message: " + except.Message + "\n" +
                  "Exception Stacktrace: " + except.StackTrace + "\n" +
                  "Database Error Details: " + "\n" +
                  "Monster ID: " + monsterID + "\n" +
                  "Database Table: " + "\n" +
                  "Error Message: " + "\n" +
                  "Stacktrace: " + stacktrace);

              SendEmail.SendEmail(Settings.mailport, Settings.mailhost, Settings.mailtimeout, Settings.mailusername, Settings.mailpassword, Settings.mailfrom, Settings.mailto, "Database Error - Unable to update Error Log", "Message: " + except.Message + "\n" + "Stacktrace: " + except.StackTrace);
          }
    }
```

}

The error is:

'clsSaveError.clsSaveError.dbContext' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

I know this is a generic error but I am not sure why it is occurring now. Thanks for the input!

Comment: It is creating a new instance of the table tblErrors so that I can save the data to the corresponding table fields in the database. It started happening after merging the code to TFS and pulling it back out of TFS. The table exists in the database. I have rebuilt the project called clsSaveError and the corresponding clsLinqToSQL project as well. I have also tried reconnecting to the database and pulling the new set of tables straight from the database and that all works fine but the error still occurs.

Comment: dbContext.tblErrors err = new dbContext.tblErrors();

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring a variable here:

```
clsLinqToSQL.K12DataClassesDataContext dbContext = new clsLinqToSQL.K12DataClassesDataContext();
```

Then trying to use that variable as a type here:

```
dbContext.tblErrors err = new dbContext.tblErrors();
```

If `dbContext` is the name of a type, don't declare variables by the same name.  If it isn't the name of a type, then I have no idea what the above line of code is trying to do.

Your type names and variable names are entirely breaking C# conventions, making the code difficult to read.  For example:

```
public clsSendEmail.clsSendEmail SendEmail = new clsSendEmail.clsSendEmail();
```

Your type names are lowercase, and your variable is uppercase.  This is backward from standard convention.  Prepending `cls` to *every* type name isn't helping.

Comment: Do you understand what I am trying to accomplish? How would you go about doing it? This code works fine for the rest of the project - same naming convention and all. It is just this class that I am having the issue with.

Comment: @KyleDenney: It looks like what you're trying to accomplish is to declare a variable called `err` of type `dbContext.tblErrors`.  But you have a variable called `dbContext` already in that scope.  This is confusing the compiler.  Don't name variables the same name as types.  Your naming convention makes it difficult to tell the difference between variables and types.  Hence your confusion.

Comment: I am trying to reference the LINQ to SQL table tblError. The only way I know to do this is to create an instance of the class where the LINQ to SQL DataContext is located - clsLinqToSQL - that instance name is dbContext. How else can I accomplish this?

Comment: @KyleDenney: Is `tblErrors` a property on the `dbContext` *object*, or a sub-type on the `dbContext` *type*?  Your code (and, again, your naming conventions), make that very unclear.  If it's a property on the object then you can reference it directly where you need it.  You don't have to create a variable to copy it.  I'm not sure how else to explain this.  Variables and the *types* of variables are two different things.

Comment: Yes tblErrors is a property of the dbContext. dbContext is short for DataContext for LINQ to SQL.

Comment: @KyleDenney: Yes, I know what `dbContext` *usually* means, but with your naming conventions all bets are off on what something *usually* means.  If it's just a property then why are you trying to use it as a type?  Why not just say `var err = dbContext.tblErrors;` to create a variable which references that property.  Or why not just reference the property directly?  Or are you trying to create an instance of whatever `tblErrors` is a collection of?  In that case, don't use the collection as the type.  What is the type of that collection?  Create an instance of *that* type.